# Targeting a meta tag and its values with XPath in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I'm trying to complete a IMPORTXML function that targets a `<meta>` tag and it's `content=` value. I'm not a developer and I know I'm missing something basic, but I can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Partial IMPORTXML Function**

I believe this function gets to the level containing the  tag I'm trying to pull.

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/273646","//div[@id='skuActions']//table//tr[@id='trOneTimeDeliv']/td")
```

**I'm trying to pull the content value of $34.99 out of the tag below.**

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="$34.99" />
```

**It is found in the URL below**

https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/273646/Office-Depot-Brand-White-Copy-Paper/

Comment: "We're Sorry. We are unable to process your last request." on your URL.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry, the original was a url to the 'view source'.  This one is to the actual page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about this? `https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/273646/Office-Depot-Brand-White-Copy-Paper/` is in a cell "A1".

#### Pattern 1 :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@itemprop='price'][1]/@content")
```

[image]

#### Pattern 2 :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='border_bottom'][3]//div[@class='unified_price_row unified_sale_price red_price']//span[@class='price_column right']")
```

[image]

#### Note :

- Error sometimes occurs for this URL. It was found that the reason is that the login screen is displayed. At that time, please try again.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.